# I am getting a node.js module.js:473 error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I have recently install the latest version of node.js (v8.6.0 Current). I am currently learning node.js but I'm having trouble using the command line to get into my programming files as per the lessons. I keep getting the below error message. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong. I've restarted my computer and reinstalled node.js several times already.

Thank you,
Edwin

```
module.js:473
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\User\edwin\desktop'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:453:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (modlue.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3
```

Comment: You have that error when you do what, exactly?

Comment: provide us with your code

Comment: My apologies. I get the error when I try to enter my programming file. The file is named Variables and I entered

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in the code you have written you either have a line like :
`... require("C:\User\edwin\desktop")` or 
`require(".")` or 
`require('desktop')` or similar.

This is looking for an `index.js` file in the folder which is not there, or a module named `desktop` that you have not installed. If you show us your source file, we can actually tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use npm run dev in the place of node run dev in your terminal.

Comment: i had experienced the same problem